# Applet + MS Access

Tags: java, html, database, ms-access

This is a more specific version of my other question. I have created an applet that should communicate with my MS Access database. It works fine when I run it through a compiler, but when I embed the .class file in an html page and open the html page, it runs but none of the changes it is supposed to make to the database actually happen and it cannot retrieve data from the database. I am eventually going to publish this html file to a secure network. The applet should communicate directly with the database on the computer, without servlets/sockets/etc (even though this is supposedly not good practice). If a different computer accesses the html page, it should be able to run the applet and make changes to the database on the host computer, but it need not allow the applet any special access to its own files, since they are not being changed, only the database on the host computer is. So I see no reason to make it a signed applet, because that will enable the applet to make changes to any computer, not just its own. I run Vista so policy tool is not available.

Note: the html file, the class file, and the java source file are all on my computer in the same folder, and this is the way it will stay. The html file is not yet published, I just created it myself to test the applet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an applet embedded in html page to communicate with database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754117/using-an-applet-embedded-in-html-page-to-communicate-with-database)

Comment: I voted to close this question.  It would be better to edit the original question with additional information, if needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have actually attempted this sort of thing before. I think your problem lies in the nature of an applet.

Applets are downloaded and run by the client machine, so if the database that you are trying to access exists on the server, the client probably does not have access to the database location on the server. And as we all know, code from the client machine is not to be trusted.

It may be easier to rewrite your page as a servlet, as the servlet lives on the server and presumably has access to the database. Your servlet can then send html and receive form data back and forth between the client and server.

If your heart is set on an applet front end, you could send http messages back to a servlet which would then perform the database operations. This option would be far more secure and a lot easier to implement permission-wise.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks Erik. My heart was set on an applet, but I looked into servlets as well since it may be simpler just to revamp the structure of my code. The problem now is that I tried to import javax.servlet.*, but DrJava claims that this package does not exist. Also, I was under the impression that servlets could not be a front end since they had no GUI.

Comment: @MrTuesday -1 *"I think your problem lies in the nature of an applet. ..the client probably does not have access to the database location on the server."*  A sand-boxed applet can easily 'phone home' to its own server (including to a DB).  There are so many errors in your post that "you're not even wrong". *"let me know if you have additional questions."* Please learn more about applets before providing any additional answers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Could you please explain how the applet can "phone home" to its own server? This is basically the problem I face.

Comment: AJAX is built on the principle of keeping a lot of things client-side and communicating with the server only when needed. On the other hand, an Access/Jet/ACE database is a different animal from the types of database engines that are actually appropriate for use behind a web server -- Access/Jet/ACE works on the principle of having access to the file itself, but server databases offer a server-side process for communicating with the database. This can all be worked around, of course, but methods that work when the Access/Jet/ACE file is local won't work over the web.